# Is there a way for VS2010's devenv.exe /out switch to replace an existing log file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, devenv

When building using the Visual Studio 2010 devenv command line, the /out switch will append to the file if it exists.

Is there a way to force it to overwrite the file contents instead?

I'm trying to avoid needing an additional pre-build step to delete the file before automated builds.

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem, but the official MS documentation does not offer a solution for this. So I guess the answer to your question would be no.

Why do you want to avoid a pre-build step?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [/Rebuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2h6xst1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead?

Comment: /Rebuild also does an append. What makes you think it wouldn't?